# ActiveRecord merge datasets of same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model, lets say Ad, which I plan to fetch 2 datasets from, then merge them into 1. Is this possible:

```
ads = Ad.where(etc).limit(5)

if ads.length < 5
  merge = Ad.where(etc).limit(remainder)

// merge both here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord allows you to do chaining. Try this out, it will execute only one query.

```
ads = Ad.where(etc).limit(5)
ads = ads.where(etc).limit(remainder)
```

But in your case, you call the `length` method so it will execute two queries. However, you can still do chaining. User `count` method is better than `length` method because `count` will send a `COUNT(*)` to your database (faster). `length` will load all records based on the `where` conditions and do a count on array (slower).

```
ads = Ad.where(etc).limit(5)
if ads.count < 5
  ads = ads.where(etc).limit(remainder)
end
```